# cloud-init does not run when creating azure vm

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am running the below sample. For some reason, it is not executing `cloud-init-web-server.txt` when creating the VM. Is there any other step messing?

I have looked at [this azure VM tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-secure-web-server).

```
az vm create \
    --resource-group tkestvalkey \
    --name myVM \
    --image UbuntuLTS \
    --admin-username azureuser \
    --admin-password password \
    --custom-data cloud-init-web-server.txt \
    --secrets "$vm_secret"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went over the steps, it works just fine.  Make sure you are not getting any error on the commands.

I notice you password is password, it might fail validation. Try it with a stronger password or the SSH key like the tutorial.

[image]

Comment: no sure what happened it worked this time. thanks for check it out